# PHP search , but show result in next page

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, search

search.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 
    // gets value sent over search form

    $min_length = 3;
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register
            WHERE (`Username` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Firstname` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

        // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
        // articles is the name of our table

        // '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
        // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
        // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo "<p><h3>".$results['Username']."</h3>".$results['Contactnumber']."</p>";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
</body>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<body bgcolor="#919191">

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Add Package</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">View Customer</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">View Order</a></li>
</ul>

<form action="search.php" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

is that possible show result on same page instead of showing on the next page ? 
as my result is showing on blank , I wanted to show on my page, anyone know where to fix the problem ? I tried to add in , not helping .

Comment: merge search.php code in index.php will solve the problem

Comment: avoid use of mysql function() as these are now deprecated in php 7

Answer (score 1):

Well, pretty Easy, there is no way to do it in php... you need to use **AJAX**. My friend made a great AJAX library you can find on Github:

https://github.com/PDKnight/XXHR

There you Can learn the very basics and make your search work as you want!

**OR**

You Can do it with site refresh, which does not look good, But whatever...

1. Change the form action to "" (Yeah, let it blank)
2. Add your PHP to index.php
3. Call your php Only if submit was called:

   if($_POST["submit"]){
   //your php there
   }

So it might work like so.. users enters the site, Nothing happens, then inputs values to form, clicks **submit**, which causes site to refresh, and then see the results, because php knows He pressed the submit. Easy peasy lemon squeze...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). It allows you to do a backdoor request while the current page is actually loaded.

It's like your talking to someone and then quickly whisper something to another guy and the first guy doesn't know about this. In this example you are the browser, the first guy is you as person (client) and the third is the webserver.

So over AJAX it's possible to send data to a php-file and get an answer of it. Please look it up urself.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple, just remove search.php from form tag.

```
    <?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 
    // gets value sent over search form

    $min_length = 3;
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register
            WHERE (`Username` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Firstname` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

        // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
        // articles is the name of our table

        // '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
        // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
        // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo "<p><h3>".$results['Username']."</h3>".$results['Contactnumber']."</p>";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <body bgcolor="#919191">

    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">Add Package</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">View Customer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">View Order</a></li>
    </ul>

    <form action="" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="query" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: query in D:\xampp\htdocs\adminsearch1.php on line 2